# Error in activity_main.xml TableRow

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

i have an error in my xml code on eclipse, can you please help me :c

this is a part of my code:

```
<TableRow
    ....
    <TextView
        android:layout_span="3"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView2"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    ...
</TableRow>
```

the error says:

Element type `TableRow` must be followed by either attribute specifications, `>` or `/>`.

Comment: [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

Comment: You should paste your code here but, just guessing, it sounds like you are missing the closing caret  (`/>`) for your table row

Comment: i allready solve it... thanks nwn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<TableRow` this part of your code should be

```
<TableRow android:layout_width=...
          android:layout_height=...>
```

in other words - the tag should be closed